# Use different sizes in JQuery mobile project, data-icon

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to do this:
http://prntscr.com/1zk1wt
but every button in the app use `.ui-icon`style as default

```
.ui-icon {
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

When I try to use this (to make "leave", "extra" and "reset" buttons bigger)
remark: .menu_header contains .ui-icon style and this
note overrides default .ui-icon:

```
.menu_header .ui-icon {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}
```

but does not affect the whole button and 
I take this http://prntscr.com/1zk2j7. As you see, the text placed under block 18x18px.((
Html code to initialize buttons:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="out" data-iconpos="top" data-inline="true" data-      mini="true"id="winner_screen_leave_game_button" class="ui-btn-left custom_icon_button" style="color: #4d4d4d;">Leave Game</a>
```

How to place text under the button image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. I used standart html syntax for create buttons with different size.